# How to sequentially load data using rxjs? in each sequence might be several calls

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular5, angular8

`const dates = [{start:'03/06/2020', end: '03/09/2020'}, {start:'03/12/2020', end: '03/03/2021'}, ...]`

`const data =  service.get(page = 1, dates[0]) and service.get(page = 2, dates[0])`  returns data but as shown there could be n number of pages... and each page data needs to be fetched before calling for another date.

`data.subscribe(resp=> somesubject.next(this.values = this.values.concat(resp)))` 'resp' is result of each api call. All the values for each date basically concatenated in client.

What is the best way to handle this? Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: How do you calculate `page`? Your code suggests it is hard coded. Otherwise I think you just want a loop for each `page`

Comment: How do you know how many pages you have to fetch?

Comment: first call returns pagination object which has number of pages, total records etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With these preliminary assumptions / hypotheses :

- `dates` is an array of dates intervals (or ranges) to be able to query some data
- `PageResponse` is a type of response returned from `api` service, which contains current page number returned, and items returned.
- `getPage` is a method which returns an `Observable<Response>` for a specific date interval and page number. (starting from 0). When no more result, response contains an empty array of items.

```js
  export type PageResponse = {
    page: number;
    items: any[];
  };
```

```js
  getPage(dateInterval: any, page: number): Observable<Response> {
    // use dateInterval to query expected data...
    // or call service.get...
    return this.http.get<PageResponse>(`http://.../pages/${page}`);
  }
```

You can do

```js
from(dates)
      .pipe(
        concatMap(dateInterval =>
          this.getPage(dateInterval, 0).pipe(
            expand(response => {
              if (response.items?.length) {
                return this.getPage(dateInterval, response.page + 1);
              } else {
                return EMPTY;
              }
            }),
            map((page) => page.results)
          )
        ),
        mergeAll(),
        toArray()
      )
      .subscribe(results => {
         // results is a flat array of all items returned
         ...
      });
```

Of course, this code is an example and need to be adapt to your situation. Some type are missing (for instance items), but it's just to keep example simple here.

Comment: If this resolved your issue, please mark this as your answer to close the question. Thank you!